# How can I fix the formatting of my CV?

Tags: tables

I am currently writing a CV using the template found at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/data-science-tech-resume-template/zcdmpfxrzjhv, but am having trouble reformatting the document after adding more labels to the skills section. I have tried to increase the number of items\columns\rows that can be in the list, but have been unsuccessful.

The error messages I am getting are:
 \endtemplate

l.5 \skills{Frameworks} &
& Numpy, Sci-Kit learn, Tidyverse, ggplot, Pandas,...
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.

\endtemplate

l.6 \skills{Soft Skills} & &
Curiosity, strong time management, good communi...
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.

The code that is being used is as follows:

```
    \begin{tabular}{p{11em} p{1em} p{43em}} %p{43em} p{43em}}
\skills{Tools and Programming Languages} & &    Python, Git, Java, SQL R, HTML, Scheme, JavaScript, \LaTeX, MarkDown, PHP, Bash, Batch, Powershell, Visual Studio, Pycharm, Eclipse \\
\skills{Quantitative Research} & &  Mathematical optimization, Mathematical Modeling, Probabilistic and Statistical visualisation R, MySQL, Microsoft Excel, Access, Power BI \\
\skills{Databases} & &  Microsoft Access, MySQL, PHP MyAdmin, Microsoft SQL server
\skills{Frameworks} & & Numpy, Sci-Kit learn, Tidyverse, ggplot, Pandas, Dask
\skills{Soft Skills} & & Curiosity, strong time management, good communication and negotiation skills, superb problem solving and creativity, continually improving teamwork, excellent analytical skills, adaptable, strong attention to detail, strong work ethic, accepting criticism
\end{tabular}


    \documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%====================
% OFFICIAL PUBLIC OVERLEAF TEMPLATE
% https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/data-science-tech-resume-template/zcdmpfxrzjhv
% 
%====================
%
% Resume template for data scientists, a complement to data-science-tech-cover-letter-template:
% https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/data-science-tech-cover-letter-template/gbrcqktbsfxf
%
% Files:        resume.tex: Main file
%               _header.tex: header code
%               TLCresume.sty: style file containing formatting details
%               section/objective: https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/resumes-cover-letters/resume-objective-examples
%               section/skills: table of skills
%               section/experience: projects or roles
%               section/education: schools and stuff
%               section/activities: optional, could comment out in resume.tex.
%
% Editor:       https://github.com/TimmyChan 
%               https://www.linkedin.com/in/timmy-l-chan/
%               
% Last Updated: March 24th, 2022
%
%====================


\usepackage{TLCresume}

%====================
% CONTACT INFORMATION
%====================
\def\name{} % Name Here
\def\phone{() }
\def\city{, }
\def\email{}
\def\LinkedIn{} % linkedin.com/in/______
\def\github{} % github username
\def\gitlab{} % gitlab username
\def\role{} % JOB TITLE

\input{_header}
\begin{document}
\input{sections/objective}

\section{Skills}
\input{sections/skills}

\section{Education}
\input{sections/education}

\section{Technical Experience}
\input{sections/experience}



% make a newpage wherever it is a clean break
% \newpage
\section{Coursework projects}
\input{sections/Coursework projects}

\section{Personal projects}
\imput{sections\Personal Projects}

\section{Activities}
\input{sections/activities}


\end{document}

l.65 \imput
       {sections\Personal Projects}
```

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.65 \imput{sections\Personal
Projects}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

The output can be seen below:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please [edit] your post, highlight the code, and click `{}`.  Make sure that the displayed code matches the spacing you have.  As it is, TeX.SE has lost all of your newlines, so that your code is all jumbled up.

Comment: Presumably `\imput` should be `\input`.

Comment: Also, in addition to the `\input`/`\imput` problem, you need \\  at the end of the "Databases" and "Frameworks" rows in the skills table. Finally you need to fill in the contact info. Do that, and I think it should work.